# Why is there always a cat or dog in the Careers "Work From Home" ads?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

[image: Work. From Home. (Stack Overflow Careers)]

Any specific reason for putting cat or dog in front of laptop instead of some developer?

Comment: Because we're *anti-fish*!

Comment: Guys, a human found their way onto this site again, and actually doesn't know we're actually all [developer pets](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f8/Internet_dog.jpg)!

Comment: :-)  lol, is that the logic behind it ?

Comment: Maybe, seems likely, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Conspiracy time! Companies with a WFH policy would probably want the employees' motivation for working from home to be that they can pet their cats, rather than taking care of kids. Kids are a huge distraciton while animals may enhance work performance. A lot of childfree people have pets so this way they target a childfree demographic.

Comment: Cats are cute. Humans are ugly. ;)

Comment: I think the advertising has done its job, would you have looked at this ad if it included a cheesy 90's developer smiling?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176641/what-do-the-dog-laptop-mean-in-the-stack-overflow-careers-advertisement

Comment: woof? http://freefall.purrsia.com/ff2300/fc02235.htm

Comment: Erm.. _anti-fish_?! We should organise a country wise strike for poor @Tunaki :-(

Comment: It should be a rubber duck instead of cat. Developers love rubber ducks :)

Comment: The dog means, nobody knows in internet that you are a dog(jerk) xD

Comment: Meh.... bite me.

Answer (score 31):

Personification is great for portraying people without introducing any kind of bias.

You see a cat or a dog. Cats and dogs are cute. The "person" they create for the purpose of the ad:

- Does not have a gender that you can determine
- Does not have a race that you can determine
- Does not have a religion that you can determine
- Does not have an age that you can determine
- Only alienates people that hate cats, or laptops.

Maybe we could have used some storm troopers or droids instead, but I think cats and dogs are safer when it comes to *not* making people feel like they wouldn't belong as the 'person' we're trying to depict working happily and comfortably from home.

That's just my take - someone from our ad or marketing team is pretty likely to chime in too :)

Comment: Kittens are obviously cuter than dogs though.

Comment: Kittens rock the world! `:)` We are all slaves of cats! `:D`

Comment: Obviously, we need to fix this ad - it should be a blue footed bird.

Comment: Actually, dogs are considered unclean in Islam, and many Muslims avoid contact with them for that reason.

Comment: @bluefeet in that case, we should have an emu and a ninja puppy as well!

Comment: Unicorns are better...